# MySql .Net Connector seems to return the wrong type to DataTable

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a column in a MySQL table defined as an int(11). After "filling" a DataTable with a select statement, the corresponding column of the DataTable has a type of Int64! Has anyone seen this behavior? I  would expect the column to be an Int32!

Comment: Can you specify your mysql and connector/.net version?
I am running 5.0.51a-24+lenny4 with connector 6.1.3 and I get Int32 type as expected.

Comment: I'm using MySQL 5.1.25 with connector 6.0.3

Comment: Its also, not consistent. Within the same table, some int(11) fields are correctly  returned as Int32 and others Int64 - this is bizzare!

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this but found this explaining what the int(11) means, it might not be relevant to your question but more of a side note though:

http://everythingmysql.ning.com/profiles/blogs/data-type-confusion-what-is-an

Comment: Yes, that's his point - even though it is declared as INT(11) it is still only 32 bits in mysql, so the data type should be Int32. I suspect somewhere this mysql-specific knowledge gets lost, and instead the code sees it as a generic 11 digit integer - which does require Int64.